# PHP, MYSQL problem with <select> and final insert inside <php> action

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I got problem with my code, can't figure out how to make my script work.
I wanted to make on my HTML site, select dropdown list to choose parents for Kid, that imports data from my database, and this works, i can see things listed.

This is code to connect DB and determine `$resultimie`

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','aplikacja_kolonijna');
    if(!$con)
    {
        echo 'Data base not found';
    }

    $resultimie=$con->query("select concat(imie_opiekun,' ',nazwisko_opiekun) as full_name_opiekun from opiekun");


?>
```

And  this is for show variables as options in select, it works.  BUT.. check below

```
Opiekun Prawny:<select id="text_box_od" name="fullname_opiekun" >
  <?php
      while($rows = $resultimie->fetch_assoc())
    {
         $full_name_opiekun = $rows['full_name_opiekun'];
         echo "<option value='.$full_name_opiekun'>$full_name_opiekun</option>";            
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

But also made form  to upload information about "KID" and also includes foreign key about Parent ID, so i made action in php, I won't post it because it's really long, all i can say is that similar form ( insert)  worked on every other  site i've made, but not  this one with this select option.

This is my Action i use for FORM.

```
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','aplikacja_kolonijna');
    if(!$con)
    {
        echo 'Data base not found';
    }

    $imie_dziecko = $_POST['imie_dziecko'];
    $nazwisko_dziecko = $_POST['nazwisko_dziecko'];
    $pesel_dziecko = $_POST['pesel_dziecko'];
    $data_urodzenia_dziecko = $_POST['data_urodzenia_dziecko'];
    $nr_kontaktowy_dziecko = $_POST['nr_kontaktowy_dziecko'];
    $miejscowosc_zamieszkania_dziecko = $_POST['miejscowosc_zamieszkania_dziecko'];
    $ulica_zamieszkania_dziecko = $_POST['ulica_zamieszkania_dziecko'];
    $kod_pocztowy_dziecko = $_POST['kod_pocztowy_dziecko'];
    $diety_dziecko = $_POST['diety_dziecko'];
    $choroby_dziecko = $_POST['choroby_dziecko'];
    $lekarstwo_dziecko = $_POST['lekarstwo_dziecko'];
    $fullname_opiekun = $_POST['fullname_opiekun'];

    $choose_opiekun = "(SELECT id_opiekun FROM opiekun where concat(imie_opiekun,' ',nazwisko_opiekun) like '%$fullname_opiekun%')";

    $sql = "Insert into 'dziecko' (id_opiekun,imie_dziecko,nazwisko_dziecko,pesel_dziecko,data_urodzenia_dziecko,nr_kontaktowy_dziecko,miejscowosc_zamieszkania_dziecko,ulica_zamieszkania_dziecko,kod_pocztowy_dziecko,diety_dziecko,choroby_dziecko_dziecko,lekarstwa_dziecko) values ('$choose_opiekun','$imie_dziecko','$nazwisko_dziecko','$pesel_dziecko','$data_urodzenia_dziecko','$nr_kontaktowy_dziecko','$miejscowosc_zamieszkania_dziecko','$ulica_zamieszkania_dziecko','$kod_pocztowy_dziecko','$diety_dziecko','$choroby_dziecko','$lekarstwo_dziecko')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if(!$sql)       
        echo 'nie dodano wpisu'


?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Dodano wpis!');
    </script>

<?php
header("refresh:0.1; url=add_dziecko_admin.php");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

There is `$chose_opiekun`  where  i declared select to determine parent's (opiekun) ID via Concat of name and surname, in phpmy admin, this select works, and shows ID, so i don't know why this doesnt work  in `$sql query`. There is no Error (even if i change "refresh" to 10). It says like it all works, also there is pop up that data was entered into database... but it doesn't , there is no new entry.

So my question is..  What can i possibly do, to make this form works, it's really important for  me.

Thanks for every answer.
P.S. I  also tried without `$choose_opiekun`, and paste it directly into insert query, as id_opiekun value.

Comment: simply injecting `$chose_opiekun` SQL into your INSERT query could break it. what is the problem to fetch `id_opiekun ` and then (if exists) to put it afterwards into your INSERT?

Comment: also, during INSERT you are NOT checking for any SQL error. `if(!$sql)` is always TRUE, you know? :) `mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));` will do a magic.

Comment: Point is to pick from dropdown select on site, concated name and surname of parent, and then, in action, look for ID, where name and surname is LIKE choosen on site in form,  it's my first php experience so please use simply language for me ;P

Comment: Your code in second comment, really helped :D i just fixed some errors, but there is new  one, looks like tough one

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`aplikacja_kolonijna`.`dziecko`, CONSTRAINT `FK_opiekun_dziecko` FOREIGN KEY (`id_opiekun`) REFERENCES `opiekun` (`id_opiekun`))

Comment: wide open to sql injections see : **How can I prevent SQL injection** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Okay found out , that my way was also good, but problem was...

```
Opiekun Prawny:<select id="text_box_od" name="fullname_opiekun" >
  <?php
      while($rows = $resultimie->fetch_assoc())
    {
         $full_name_opiekun = $rows['full_name_opiekun'];
         echo "<option value='.$full_name_opiekun'>$full_name_opiekun</option>";            
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

There was " . "  before $full_name_opiekun, and it was searching in my DB for ".name surname" instead of 'name surname' so it was always bad value in return because there wasn't such entry started with dot.

Answer (score -1):

This is not the best approach at all, but it gives you the concept.

1. Execute a separate `SELECT` to obtain needed ID;
2. Execute `INSERT` and JS alert() only if the ID exists:

```
<?php
    // do SELECT
    $sql = "SELECT id_opiekun FROM opiekun where concat(imie_opiekun,' ',nazwisko_opiekun) like '%$fullname_opiekun%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $choose_opiekun = $row['id_opiekun'];

        //do INSERT
        $sql = "Insert into 'dziecko' (id_opiekun,imie_dziecko,nazwisko_dziecko,pesel_dziecko,data_urodzenia_dziecko,nr_kontaktowy_dziecko,miejscowosc_zamieszkania_dziecko,ulica_zamieszkania_dziecko,kod_pocztowy_dziecko,diety_dziecko,choroby_dziecko_dziecko,lekarstwa_dziecko) values ('$choose_opiekun','$imie_dziecko','$nazwisko_dziecko','$pesel_dziecko','$data_urodzenia_dziecko','$nr_kontaktowy_dziecko','$miejscowosc_zamieszkania_dziecko','$ulica_zamieszkania_dziecko','$kod_pocztowy_dziecko','$diety_dziecko','$choroby_dziecko','$lekarstwo_dziecko')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('Dodano wpis!');
        </script>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: i 've change code to your version, but i dunno, why i always get error,  when i input " { " inside <?php code
 <br/>
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in D:\xampp\htdocs\inzynierska\dziecko\action_add_dziecko_admin.php on line 24

Comment: okay, firgured out, there was missing ")", but now, it's passing, there is notification that was added, but it's not.. no error, also